# Unable to detect the removal of nfc tag in android

Tags: android, nfc

How to check that Nfc tag is removed from my phone .After attaching the nfctag it is ready to write but when i want to detect the nfcremoval  by using **nfctag.isEnabled()** but its not working . where nfctag is nfcTag. It is showing underline below 
`if(!nfctag.isenable()`

Answer (score 0):

What's "nfctag" ?

[Tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html) don't have `isEnable`

[NfcAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html) have a `isEnable` but it's to know if NFC is enabled or not on device

> Return true if this NFC Adapter has any features enabled.

There's a method `isConnected` on `TagTechnology` classes `NfcA` `NfcB` `IsoDep` ...

> isConnected
>
> Helper to indicate if I/O operations should be possible.
>   Returns true if connect() has completed, and close() has not been
>   called, and the Tag is not known to be out of range. 
>   Does not cause RF
>   activity, and does not block.
>  Returns    true if I/O operations should
>   be possible

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh Is it useful ?